# Can’t create plain C++ project in Qt creator - no valid kits found

Tags: c++, qt-creator

This is a question about Qt Creator 2.8.0. When I go to

> File>>New File or Project>>Non-Qt Project>>Plain C++ Project

Then I get to [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/706/s0y6.png/) page. When I press “Next” then I get to [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/0gx6.png/) page and get the error:

> No valid kits found

I can’t press “Next”. I can click on "options" which takes me to [this](http://imageshack.us/f/38/qas5.png/) page. I am using the latest version of Qt creator (2.8.0) installed on fully updated Fedora 19 64bit. What is a kit and how can I add it so that I can create plain C++ project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just solved it. I had to change “Qt version” from “None” to “Qt 4.8.5 in PATH (System)”. Now the kit shows correctly.

Comment: when i try to add qt version it shows me browse and then the browse button leads to some qmake file which i dont have